# How to run selenium on an actual webserver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium, browser-automation

I've no idea on how to do this and all the documentation that I could find by google did not help. A while back I was introduced to selenium through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo) and now that I'm more comfortable with it, I want my selenium "bot" to run on a webserver 24/7, receiving orders from me through facebook messenger (something I already did with it running on my local machine).

I tried to find answers online and was overwhelmed by the amount of information, finding nothing that is clear to understand. All the pages I've been through require me to learn about a large array of things and have been very specific about their tools. And some times I try to follow along something just to receive an error I don't understand nor is it explained on said something how to fix it.

I also asked this question on Reddit only to be downvoted without answer. I've no idea how to run selenium + chrome on a server.

Take me for the stupidest person on earth, How can I do this in the most clear steps? I'd prefer to use chrome with selenium, through python or php.

Comment: What server are you asking about?

Comment: @Prophet I'm talking about having my selenium bot run online through a free hosting service. This specifically : https://infinityfree.net/ . I don't know the details of their server technology though. I'm pretty new to servers overall.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure you understand what are you asking about. This seems not being related to Selenium.

Comment: @Prophet I'm not asking about the specifics of running my bot on said service, if that's what you mean. It's a general question. What would be a better question in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by making your chromedriver run headlessly. I was introduced to it by [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LN1a0JoKlX8). a headless browser means a web browser without a graphical user interface. Headless browsers provide automated control of a web page in an environment similar to your local browser and you can get screenshots too.

If headless browser is giving you an error which can't be resolved(like screen sharing error), then you can try [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/) or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) like platforms